# Jquery $.fn variable scope

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I faced a problem. I wrote my jquery component like below:

```
(function ( $ ) {

$.fn.addSocialShare = function() {

    this.append(getButtonHTML());
    return this;
};

var getButtonHTML = function(){
    var html;
    $.get('myUrl', function(data){
        html = data; // data is defined, request ok
    })        
    return html;
}
})( jQuery );
```

The problem is that `html` variable is not defined when I return it. How I can fix it? Where is my mistake?

Comment: its because of the asynchronous behaviour of ajax call. You just cant return values like that.

Comment: And what is the solution?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but try $.get('url', function(data){html = data;}).done(function(){return html;});